# How to specify a scratch output directory in Nextflow?

Tags: nextflow

I have started to read Nexflow's documentation and [found that](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html?highlight=stageout#scratch) one can specify a `scratch` directory for the execution. Once the task is complete, [one can use](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html?highlight=stageout#stageoutmode) the `stageOutMode` directive to copy the output files from `scratch` to `storeDir`.

The output files to be copied are specified by the `output` directive. My question is the following: is it possible to specify entire directories as output so that they would be copied recursively from `scratch` to `storeDir`? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the [path output qualifier](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#output-path) will capture process outputs (files, directories, etc) recursively. All you need to do is specify the (top-level) directory in your output declaration, like in the example below:

```
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

process test {

    scratch '/tmp/my/path'

    stageOutMode 'copy'

    storeDir '/store/results'

    input:
    val myint

    output:
    path "outdir-${myint}"

    script:
    def outdir = "outdir-${myint}/foo/bar/baz"

    """
    mkdir -p "${outdir}" 
    touch "${outdir}/${myint}.txt"
    """
}

workflow {

    ch = Channel.of( 1..3 )

    test(ch)
}
```

Setting the [stageOutMode](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#stageoutmode) directive just changes the how the output files are staged out from the scratch directory to the **work directory**. I.e. this directive does **not** change how process results are staged into the storeDir directory.

The [storeDir](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#storedir) directive changes what finally happens to the files listed in the output declaration such that they are **moved** from the work directory into the specified storeDir directory.

Comment: thank you. Please allow me one more question: if I define `scratch '$tmppath'`, and execute the script on a SLURM cluster, will `$tmppath` be substituted at runtime? My scheduler allocates a temporary directory with the JOBID in its name which is only allocated when the job starts running.

Comment: @Botond Yes, as long as the variable is single quoted like you've got above. Our PBS Pro scheduler does the same thing and sets a variable called `$TMPDIR` which will point to something like `/scratch/pbs.36569355.hpcpbs01` when the job starts. This directory is only created when the job starts and will be cleaned up automatically when it finishes. Nextflow will try to write all output in a sub-directory using a unique id, for example: `/scratch/pbs.36569355.hpcpbs01/nxf.6S4nL9mY3p/outdir-1/foo/bar/baz/1.txt`.